# Automatically generate a short description of a page when a user posts a link

Tags: entities, navigation

On facebook, google plus and similar websites, when someone posts a link, the thumbnail and short description of the page is automatically generated. See the screenshot below.

Is it possible to this in Drupal 7 ? If yes, how? Is there any module for it?

[image]

Comment: Is node teaser what you need?

Comment: @ninjascorner: No. When someone pastes url of any website, the thumbnail and description should come automatically,

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source for that page, you'll see this

```
<meta name='description' content='In honor of Wolfenstein 3D&#039;s 20th anniversary, the game will be released for free to play in browser today.'/>
```

Should be fairly straightforward to grab that!

Comment: Straightforward?Exactly how?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but you can grab some meta tags with get_meta_tags http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php - or to grab opengraph data (which if available is ideal for this kind of preview but won't be included in get_meta_tags because the tags don't have a name attribute) I've found this library to be very helpful https://github.com/scottmac/opengraph

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the meta tags you have set. The easiest way to accomplish this is by installing the [Meta tags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module.

Once enabled, you can navigate to the configuration page and set configuration for auto-generated tags. If you need to have specific tags for a node, you can edit that node and set the meta tags there.

You should enable the Open Graph meta tags submodule, as Facebook looks for those tags when you want to share on Facebook. Whenever you update the Open Graph tags, run it through the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) so you can see what Facebook will grab. Most of the time, Facebook should grab whatever images are available on the page and use those as thumbnails.

I use a combination of [Tweet Button](http://drupal.org/project/tweetbutton), [Facebook Share](http://drupal.org/project/facebookshare) and [Google Plus One](http://drupal.org/project/google_plusone) but i'm sure there are "all-in-one" shares that you can use. The most important thing remember is that if the meta tags aren't correct in the HTML, then they probably won't work correctly when you try to share your page.

Comment: I think the OP was after the other side of this - grabbing previews from external sites, not creating his own meta tags.